# semi direct of quaternionic group

Tags: group-theory

Hi I'm having trouble understanding why the quaternionic group cannot be written as a semi-direct product in a non-trivial way. Is there a proof of why this is the case?

Answer (score 3):

The only non trivial subgroups of $\mathbf{Q}$ are $\{1,-1\}$, $\{i\}$, $\{j\}$ and $\{k\}$. Since one needs at least one group of order $2$ in the decomposition $\mathbf{Q}=GH$ it must be $\{1,-1\}$, but this group is the center of $\mathbf{Q}$ so cannot be a factor of the decomposition.